# Not able to get geolocation IP from Teams Desktop App

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I am trying to pull geolocation details using a custom application from within Teams.
Things work fine when I am logging to teams in browser but same thing dosen't work in Desktop application.

Any suggestion what is going wrong, below is the code and error

## navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
logger.debug("geolocation : Your current position is Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + ", " + "Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude );
},
function (error) {
logger.debug("geolocation : ERROR = " + error.code + ", message = " + error.message );
}, { timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 75000 }
);

Below error is coming :

ERROR = 2, Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE.

I have enabled all the permission from Teams and system level, still error is coming.

Comment: Have you tried putting www.googleapis.com into the `validDomains` section in the manifest for your application?

Answer (score 0):

The navigation.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() API isn't currently supported in the Teams Desktop Client.

Reference Document-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/native-device-permissions?tabs=mobile%2Cteamsjs-v2%2Cmobile1#use-teams-apis-to-get-device-permissions

[image]